# FCM method to determine if token/user has disabled push Notifciations

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know there are methods to check both iOS and Android to see if the user has locally disabled push notifications for an app, that is done within the app itself.  But if a user disables push notifications for an app is this reported back to FCM?  Does FCM know not to send a notification to that user and if so, is there anyway of pulling that info out of FCM.

The reason for this question is if the user hasn't used the app in a while and they disabled push notifications - without the user starting the app (thus getting updated tokens/checking for permissions) there is no way to know the user disabled push notifications - unless we can extract that from FCM.

And along these same lines, if a user has uninstalled the app, does FCM get updated that the token is now invalid due to app removal and removes it from its db - and if so, is there anyway to way to extract this from FCM?

In both cases, we need to either update our DB that the user has disabled push notifications (and possibly use alternate communication methods) or mark the user as 'uninstalled' and thus remove that user from any app communication method (fcm, sms, email).